# Some posts inserted using Blogger API not displayed on main page

Tags: api, google-apps-script, blogger, google-apps-script-api

I am using Blogger API to insert posts. Go through the following blog to understand the problem:

Link: https://post-testing123.blogspot.com/

In this blog I have 7 posts:

5 posts with title of format 'Title #no'- are created with API request.

2 posts with title of format 'Manual #no'- are created manually.

Manual posts were created before API posts.

In this blog, I have set the number of posts to be displayed on the main page to 3.

So, on main page 3 out of 5 posts created with API are visible.

On clicking on Older, only the 2 manual posts are displayed and the 2 API posts left are not displayed.

In archives all 7 posts are displayed.

And if I set the number of posts to be displayed on the main page to a large number like 30.
Then, all 7 posts are displayed correctly.

I have tried changing the theme but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for this, it is a bug in Blogger.

It occurs when two or more posts have same timestamp (Same minute, not same seconds or milliseconds).

So, when you post using API (especially using Google Apps Script), a lot of your posts are likely to have the same the timestamp.

Something similar is stated here:

https://support.google.com/blogger/thread/2238679?hl=en&authuser=0

Hope it helps.